# How to deserialize my data that I sent to my webservice?

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services, deserialization

How do I deserialize this string that I sent as a json object in asp.net webservice.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://server/NCO/webservice.asmx/GetNRIC");   

post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

obj.put("ic", "s1111111b");

post.setEntity(new StringEntity(obj.toString(), "UTF-8"));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need a utility class which includes a method like the following.

```
 public static T JsonDeserialize<T> (string jsonString)
 {
     DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
     T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
     return obj;
 }
```

Check out [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET) for more details. Anyway you will find this serializing and deserializing scenario easier if you use a Data Transfer Object (DTO) in both the sides. Then you don't have to arrange the JSON String manually from your Android side. For that you might also need the JacksonMapper in Android side to convert the DTO to directly to a String. 
From the ASP.NET side even you can have the same entity class, therefore deserializing becomes easier

```
RequestDTO requestDTO = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<RequestDTO>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Sorry,but may I know what T and ms is?Is it a variable like string or an object?And when I return obj,is it returning it as a string or do I have to convert it from a object to a string?

Comment: Actually it is the DTO Object that you might need. Let's say that you want to retrieve a student object. You need to create a Student.class including the fields that you want and that T is supposed to be Student. Therefore, you will get a Student object returned which you passes from the client side. MemoryStream is used to specify your encoding type. In your scenario it is UTF-8.

Comment: Is there anything I need to import?It says the type or namespace cannot be found for datacontractjsonserialiser and encoding.

Comment: Did you go through the above link ? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET

This import seems to be needed : using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

Comment: Ah yes,I've fixed the import already.Now about the method to call in httpost,what would it be? /JsonDeserializer?